# A lot of long-lived access_tokens invalidated by Facebook with no reason

Tags: facebook, migration, access-token

I'm having this issue since offline_access has been deprecated and migration enabled.

I'm getting long-lived access tokens for scheduling posts on Pages. I'm using server-side authorization flow.

All pages tokens never expires (checking with Debugger Tool) but, for some app user or, in a random way for all users, good tokens are invalidated sometimes with the error: "Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons." or "...user has changed the password ...".

There are other people having the same problem http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/243018099133564

I hope anyone can help. Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is that it is a known Facebook bug.  See http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/243018099133564

Sorry, sometimes the answer is not what you desire.

Comment: I was thinking in the same way. I lost a lot of work. Hope FB dev will fix it asap. Thank you anyway. :)